# Confusion about slash notation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-matrices, anticommutator

I am confused about the slash notation and especially taking the square of a slashed operator.

Defining $\displaystyle{\not} a \, = \, \gamma^\mu a_\mu$ we have $\,\,$ $\displaystyle{\not} a \displaystyle{\not} a = a^2 $

I tried to prove that, but I can't really doing it without assumption I didn't prove. That's my (I think wrong) procedure:

$\displaystyle{\not} a \displaystyle{\not} a = \gamma^\mu a_\mu \gamma^\nu a_\nu  = \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu a_\mu  a_\nu $ assuming in the last equality that the they commute, now using the anticommutation relation of the gamma matrices :

$$\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu + \gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu =2\eta^{\mu\nu}\tag{1}$$ I say that probably $\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu= \eta^{\mu\nu}$ and substituing it in one i obtain

$$\eta^{\mu\nu}a_\mu  a_\nu\,=\, a_\mu  a^\nu \, = \, a^2$$

I don't think that's really a proof, can someone provide a right proof without the assumptions I've made?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform The assumption made is that $a_\mu$ and $\gamma^\nu$ commute.

Comment: Write $\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu = (\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu+\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu)/2$ and use the symmetry of $a_\mu a_\nu$ w.r.t. index switching in one of the terms to change the gammas' order.

Comment: @DavidZ oh, I see. To OP: Well, in general $a_\mu\in\mathbb C$ is just a complex number, and therefore it commutes with anything. In any case, you can find a more or less detailed proof in [the wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Feynman_slash_notation) (or just google "Feynman slash notation", the proof is rather standard)

Comment: The basic assumption that you have made is that the $\gamma$ matrices and the $a$ operator (whatever it is) commute.  You don't have to make the other assumption since you can add another expression with the $\mu$ and $\nu$ interchanged and cancel the extra factor of 2 at the end.  Now your first assumption is generally valid as long as you are working in Cartesian coordinates (in curvilinear coordinates the $\gamma$ matrices can become coordinate dependent and would not commute with $a$ if it contains derivatives).  Since you are free to choose Cartesian coordinates your proof is valid.

Comment: Also, $\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu=\eta^{\mu\nu}$ is incorrect; the correct expression is $\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu=\eta^{\mu\nu}+2iS^{\mu\nu}$ where $S^{\mu\nu}\equiv \frac{i}{4}[\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu]$. For the proof, see [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/238295/derivation-of-gordon-identity-from-srednicki/238477#238477) (warning: a different sign convention is used, the mostly plus metric).

Comment: Thank you all  for clarification. @AccidentalFourierTransform you said that $a_\mu$ is usually just a complex number, but for example in the Dirac equation with this slashed notation we mean the 4-vector energy momentum contracted with the gamma matrices, When we quantize write as an operator: $-i \hbar \nabla$ could you clarify that? Does it commute with the gamma matrices even if it is an operator of that kind?

Comment: @Runlikehell yes: even if it is a differential operator it commutes. *Everything* commutes with $\gamma^\mu$, except for other matrices (e.g., other gamma matrices, or products of the same).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform thank you, I had no idea of this commutation property of the gamma matrices.

Comment: @Runlikehell it is not a property of the gamma matrices in particular: any pair of objects that belong to different spaces commute.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform In the comment above, by 'spaces' do you mean vector spaces?

Comment: @Ghoster: I don't see where my comment is wrong. Both summands have the same order of gamma matrices, it's like writing $x=\frac{x+x}{2}$. Switching the order in one of the summands only works after contracting with some symmetric tensor (in this case $a_\mu a_\nu$).

Comment: @Photon Sorry…I take back what I said. I’ve deleted my comment. The person who posted the new question misread the order of the indices, and I didn’t notice.

Comment: @Ghoster: No worries at all! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This: $$\gamma ^\mu \gamma ^\nu =\eta ^{\mu \nu}$$is wrong. It would give, for example, $$\gamma ^0 \gamma ^0=1=-\gamma ^1 \gamma ^1\\ \gamma ^0 \gamma ^1=0,$$ and you can see that these relations are inconsistent.

The relation comes from the following identities: $${\not} a \, {\not} a = a_\mu a_\nu \gamma ^\mu \gamma ^\nu=a_\mu a_\nu\left(\frac{\lbrace \gamma ^\mu ,\gamma ^\nu \rbrace }{2}+\frac{[ \gamma ^\mu ,\gamma ^\nu  ]}{2}\right)=a_\mu a_\nu \frac{\lbrace \gamma ^\mu ,\gamma ^\nu \rbrace }{2}.$$ Notice: it is assumed that $a_\mu$ and $a_\nu$, whatever they are, **commute**.

The third equality is proved [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/238295/derivation-of-gordon-identity-from-srednicki/238477#238477).

The last equality is valid because contracting the symmetric tensor $a_\mu a_\nu$ with the antisymmetric indexed matrices $[\gamma ^\mu ,\gamma ^\nu]$ gives zero, that is, the contraction of a symmetric tensor ($a_\mu a_\nu \equiv A_{\mu\nu}$) and an antisymmetric tensor ($[\gamma ^\mu ,\gamma ^\nu] \equiv \Gamma^{\mu\nu}$) is zero. The proof is as follows.

\begin{eqnarray}
A_{\mu\nu} \Gamma^{\mu\nu} &=& A_{\nu\mu} (-\Gamma^{\nu\mu}) \\
                          &=& -A_{\nu\mu}\Gamma^{\nu\mu} \\
                          &=& - A_{\mu\nu} \Gamma^{\mu\nu}, \quad [\because \mu, \nu \,  \text{are dummy indices.}]
\end{eqnarray}
which implies that $A_{\mu\nu} \Gamma^{\mu\nu}$ is zero.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. You implicitly assumed right my assumption that $a_\mu$ and $\gamma^\nu$ commutes. Can you tell me why we're allowed to do that?

Comment: $a_\mu$ (if it is an operator) and $\gamma^\mu$ are in different spaces, and therefore they commute.

Comment: @Run like hell, you are welcome. Expanding a bit on Mikael's hint, the $\gamma ^\mu $'s which occur in all equations of quantum field theory commute with everything else which doesn't carry any Dirac index. This is totally clear if you write, for example ${\not} a$, element by element: $${\not}a _{\alpha \beta} = a_\mu \gamma ^{\mu }_{\alpha \beta}= \gamma ^{\mu }_{\alpha \beta} a_\mu,$$ since each $\gamma ^\mu _{\alpha \beta}$ is just a complex number.

Comment: How do we come to know that $a_{\mu} a_{\nu}$ is symmetric?

Comment: @omehoque right, thanks, it is symmetric if the $a_\mu$'s commute.