# $\displaystyle{\not}{a}\displaystyle{\not}{a} = a^2$ or $-a^2$ in Srednicki

Tags: metric-tensor, conventions, dirac-matrices, textbook-erratum, clifford-algebra

I'm confused: In Srednickis Book (Equation 37.26), he has:

$$\displaystyle{\not}{a}\displaystyle{\not}{a} = -a^2$$

However, every other source I found (for example [this SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/303981/) says that it's:

$$\displaystyle{\not}{a}\displaystyle{\not}{a} = a^2$$

What's going on here? Is there some freedom in defining $\gamma$ that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Hint: what is your metric convention ?

Comment: Srednicki has $\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}=-2\eta^{\mu\nu}$ (-+++), while the other sources have $\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}=2\eta^{\mu\nu}$ (+---), as you can check on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices)

Comment: Please note that different books use different conventions for the metric and gamma matrices. Be wary of this when comparing formulae.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When relativistic sign conventions are afoot, always consider the proof. If $\{\gamma^\mu,\,\gamma^\nu\}=\pm2\eta^{\mu\nu}I_4$, $\displaystyle{\not} a^2=\tfrac12a_\mu a_\nu\{\gamma^\mu,\,\gamma^\nu\}=\pm a^2I_4$.